# Server connection failed

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using Hostgator to create a simple website where the user can upload pictures online. The HTML and CSS code works fine however the server connection failed.

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost:3306";
$username = "brazen_test_gallary";
$password = "1234";
$dbname = "brazen_galleryexample";


$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

After I refresh my page, I get the following errors:

> Warning : mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2005): Unknown MySQL server host
>   'localhost:3306' (0)

Comment: Have you tried providing the servername without the port (just 'localhost')?

Comment: Remove the `:3306`

Comment: @alexherm I can't see how [your edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25033378) helped. Errors should not be indented. It should have been left alone.

Comment: That ^ would be a new question. What you posted in comments does not support the original question. Edit: You deleted the comment I responded to, in regards to the new error and code not included for it.

Comment: got it ill make a new question, thank u